# Select server name from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I have two tables, `files` and `servers`. Here's the schema:

```
f_id, s_id, u_id, name, size, downloads, uploaded

s_id, name, description, disk_space, used_space, enabled
```

Now, I'm trying to get some information about a particular file as well as what server it's hosted on. In the `files` table, this is determined by the `s_id` column, which is a foreign key to the `servers` table. I want to retrieve the files name, size, time it was uploaded and what server it's on. I tried this:

```
public function get_file_details()
{
    $sql= 'SELECT name, size, uploaded, server
           FROM `files` f
           JOIN `servers` s
           ON f.s_id = s.u_id
           WHERE f_id = ?
           LIMIT 1';
}
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually executing the SQL query? What _doesn't work?_ Do you receive an error?

Comment: Woops, sorry. This is the error: `Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous`. I think I understand what it means (it doesn't know where `name` comes from) but I don't know how to tell it it's coming from `servers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function get_file_details()
{
    $sql= 'SELECT f.name, size, uploaded, s.name
           FROM `files` f
           JOIN `servers` s
           ON f.s_id = s.s_id
           WHERE f_id = ?
           LIMIT 1';
}
```

3 changes: name => f.name, server => s.name, ON f.s_id = s.u_id => ON f.s_id = s.s_id

Answer (score 1):

it is showing this error because name field is present in both of the table so it becomes ambiguous. To avoid this error always add table name aliase 
Try this

```
SELECT f.name, f.size, f.uploaded, s.name
           FROM `files` f
           JOIN `servers` s ON f.s_id = s.s_id
           WHERE f_id = ?
           LIMIT 1'
```